# Ambiguous type in a simple statement Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, ambiguous, floor

I want simply add 3.5 + floor 3.5 but this error occur: 
   Ambiguous type variable 't' in constraints:
      'Fractional t'
         arising from the literal '3.5'...
      'Integral t'
         arising from a use of floor...

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is how: `3.5 + fromInteger (floor 3.5)`.

The reason for that is that the `floor`'s result must be `Integral`, but `3.5` must be `Fractional`. Both arguments of `+` must have the same type, but there is no default data type that is both `Integral` and `Fractional`, thus the error.

Comment: @adriano Be sure you accept the answer (by clicking the check mark) if it solves your issue.